# deleting pointers in a c++ map

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I have a map

```
std::map<std::string, my_class*> name2ptr;
```

I try to delete the contents of the map by first traversing through the map to delete the the my_class pointers and later clear the map. Now, I have a problem when there is only one pair in the map. The map has only one entry now

```
<"ajay", 0xabcd>
```

It crashes at delete((*itr).second). The for loop is as below.

```
name_map_type::iterator itr;
    for( itr= name2ptr.begin();itr!=name2ptr.end();itr++){
        if((*itr).second){
            delete ((*itr).second);
        }
    }
name2ptr.clear();
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: It's crashing there, but the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you've posted.  The error is almost certainly some where else in your code.

Comment: what does the destructor for my_class look like?

Answer (score 3):

Did you put a bad pointer into the map? Firstly, there is no need to check for `nullptr` on `(*itr).second`; `delete`ing a `nullptr` is perfectly OK, it won't do anything.

You should look at storing `std::shared_ptr<my_class>` as your map's value type instead of a raw pointer. That way, you just have to call `name2ptr.clear()`, and as long as nothing else is holding a reference to the object, it will be deleted.

Check out [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).